# Error with Intellij Heroku Integration

Tags: heroku, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm currently using the Intellij Heroku Integration plugin, and i'm trying to set up the basic connection to heroku. But when i try to set the SSH key, which is just a basic SSH key generated by the command

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your_email@example.com"
```

i get this error:

[image: com.heroku.api.exception.RequestFailedException]

am i supposed to do something different to generate the key?

*extra details on what i've done that might be screwing this up:
 - i tried to install the plugin on community edition (now trying with the full edition)
 - i deleted a few outdated versions of heroku on my pc and reinstalled just the CLI

any clues how to fix this? or is heroku integration just broken? i also get: 
[image: help docs missing]
when i try to click for help, so maybe the plugin files are corrupted? any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: It's a known issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-19851.

Comment: @CrazyCoder thanks for the link - at least i know i'm not crazy or stupid now. issue looks relatively new

Answer (score 1):

as @CrazyCoder mentioned this is a bug, where the API used by IntelliJ was dropped in April 2017 by Heroku.

This should be fixed with IntelliJ 2017.3 onwards.

**Edit**

Version 173.3727.22 is still shipped with the Heroku integration 1.0, so the problem remains.
You will have to manually install the new version of the plugin, found here:

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7605-heroku-integration